tabularray - cmd and \SetCell not changing bg color - how to use expand?
I would like to format cell based on their int value.
Text substitution is working but \SetCell is not working.
Update:
Reading the manual in more details, I found how to make it work with the functional package. There is an example using expand option. I am failing to use it. What I am missing ?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\prgNewFunction \funcColor {} {
    \intStepOneInline {2} {\arabic{rowcount}} {
        \intStepOneInline {1} {\arabic{colcount}} {
            \strCaseF {\cellGetText {##1} {####1}} 
                {
                    {1}{\cellSetText{##1}{####1}{\&} }
                    {2}{\cellSetStyle {##1} {####1} {bg=blue} \cellSetText{##1}{####1}{\&\&} }
                    {3}{\cellSetStyle {##1} {####1} {bg=yellow} \cellSetText{##1}{####1}{\&\&\&} }
                    {4}{\cellSetStyle {##1} {####1} {bg=red} \cellSetText{##1}{####1}{\&\&\&\&} }
                } 
                {\cellSetText{##1}{####1}{NA}} 
        }
    }
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytable1}{}{
\begin{tblr}{
    width=\columnwidth,
    colspec={XXX},
    hline{2-Y}={solid},
    vline{2-Y}={solid},
    rowsep=2mm,
    colsep=2mm,
    row{1}  ={c,m,font={\fontsize{10}{0}}, cmd={\textbf}},
    row{2-Z}={c,m,font={\fontsize{ 8}{0}}},
    process=\funcColor,
}}
{\end{tblr}}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\myswitch{m}{
    \str_case:nnF{#1}{
        {1}{\&}
        {2}{\SetCell{bg=blue}\&\&}
        {3}{\SetCell{bg=yellow}\&\&\&}
        {4}{\SetCell{bg=red}\&\&\&\&}
    }{NA}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytable2}{}{
\begin{tblr}[expand=\myswitch]{
        width=\columnwidth,
        colspec={XXX},
        hline{2-Y}={solid},
        vline{2-Y}={solid},
        rowsep=2mm,
        colsep=2mm,
        row{1}  ={c,m,font={\fontsize{10}{0}}, cmd={\textbf}},
        row{2-Z}={c,m,font={\fontsize{ 8}{0}}, cmd={\myswitch}},
}}
{\end{tblr}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    \section{With functional (Works)}

    \begin{mytable1}
        Cat1 & Cat2 & Cat3 \\
        1 & 2 & 4 \\
        1 & 3 & 0 \\
    \end{mytable1}

    \section{With expand (Fail)}

    \begin{mytable2}
        Cat1 & Cat2 & Cat3 \\
        1 & 2 & 4 \\
        1 & 3 & 0 \\
    \end{mytable2}

\end{document}


\SetCell is not expandable, so \myswitch cannot be expandable. If you use \NewExpandableDocumentCommand, you should ensure it only contains expandable stuff.
